# "Затички для вух" одним словом?

Tags: from-russian

Інколи зустрічаю "беруші" як запозичення з російської "беруши", проте в російській це слово є скороченням від "береги уши", тобто "бережи вуха", тому за безпосереднього запозичення втрачається початкове значення. З іншого боку в російській це слово давно є усталеним і не завжди асоціюється зі скороченням.

Чи правильно вживати в українській мові слово "беруші", або ж є суто українське слово? Чи може "затички для вух" є єдиним допустимим варіантом?

Answer (score 3):

Не знайшов слова "беруші" ані в традиційному СУМ-20, ані у вільнішому тлумачному на сайті Горох.

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> Беруши – (от «берегите уши») глушак, знешумник, протишумник, захисний навушник, вушна затичка, затичка для вух *(Стаття потребує додаткового обговорення)*.

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/berushi) пропонує просто:

> Затички

З іншого боку, у [вжиток](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%8F%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%20%22%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D1%96%22&ei=OdECW4PvKcK1sQGK2ZS4Dg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662) це слово вже увійшло, тож якщо вам треба його використати десь в особистому спілкуванні, просто для пояснення чогось, то я б не вагався, а ось якщо ви пишете офіційний документ, якщо вам потрібна ділова або літературна мова, то доведеться використовувати довші відповідники, поки не маємо цього слова у словниках, або користуватися словом "беруші" у лапках і додатково пояснювати його значення.

Answer (score 3):

На додачу до [сказаного P. Vovk](/a/4211):

- [Олександр Пономарів каже](//www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-44290892):

  > Це ***вушна затичка*** або ***затичка для вуха***.
- [«The Russian-Ukrainian Dictionary» у складі ABBYY Lingvo Live пропонує](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8) надає переклад ***берву́ха***, хоча авторитетність цього словника мені незрозуміла (можливо, російсько-український словник у складі ABBYY Lingvo Live базується на «Російсько-українському, українсько-російському словнику» В. Бусела видавництва «Перун» — але ані підтвердити, ані спростувати не можу — я так припускаю лише тому, що [український тлумачний словник ABBYY Lingvo Live базується на «Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)).
- [«Російсько-український народний сучасний словник» на R2U надає такі переклади для рос. *беруши*](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8&scope=rusb&dicts=10): *глушак*, *знешумник*, *протишумник*, *захисний навушник*, *вушна затичка*, *затичка для вух* — але це «народний» словник, що його заповнюють ентузіасти.
- [«Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович; 2010) надає такі переклади для англ. *earplug*](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=earplug&dicts=4): ***вушна́ за́тичка***, ***за́тичка до ву́ха***.
- Також є кілька обговорень цього питання у Facebook ([у групі «Український переклад»](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1487291391306624/), [на сторінці BBC News Ukrainian](//www.facebook.com/BBCnewsUkrainian/posts/1907577179273921), [у групі «Українська мова для всіх»](//www.facebook.com/groups/367613903441695/permalink/999215583614854/)), де пропонують зокрема такі варіанти: *бервухи* (як *бервуха*, тільки на *-и*), *беруха*, *втички*, *вухоглуш*, *вухотиш*, *вухошумопоглинач*, *вушглуш* (від *вушні глушники*), *вушні вставки*, *глушник*, *затички*, *заткнивухо*, *протишум*, *протишумові вкладки*, *слухоглуш*, *слухозахист*, *слухотиш*, *тишовух*, *тишослух*.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>На додачу [додачі пана Sasha](/a/4258) до [сказаного пана P. Vovk](/a/4211)</sup>

Коли поглянути в [словнику чужомовних слів Павла Штепи](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt), то для слова *пробка* існують замінники  *корок*, *затичка* та *чіп*. Останього слова, а саме [*ušesni čep*](//sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/U%C5%A1esni_%C4%8Dep), вживає словенська; має СУМ з трохи потрібним [означенням](http://sum.in.ua/s/chip): *конусоподібна дерев'яна пробка для закупорювання отвору в якійсь посудині*; включає [етімолоґічний словник](//goroh.in.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%87%D1%96%D0%BF), як питоме українське слово з походження псл. *čеръ*, гадаю, слово того ж корня відоміше як *за·чіп·ка*.

Отже. Замість *затичка* можна спробувати вжити також *корок* та *чіп*, оскільки друге слово коротке в 1 склад, то напрошується і *вухочіп*. А слово *затичка* легко перетворюється в *тик*, котрого знов частково [має](http://sum.in.ua/s/tyk) СУМ:  *уживається як присудок за значенням „тикатися“<sub>1 2</sub> й „тикнутися“<sub>2</sub>*; відси *вухотик*, особливо коли згадати подібного і [вживаного](//google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off) *самотик*.